# how to view backend crud from frontend yii2 advanced folder

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am using yii2 advanced app. and in frontend I am using tabsx widget from which I want to open backend\view\companies\index.php.

Is it possible to do so and how?

here is code
frontend\views\contacts\index.php

```
echo TabsX::widget([
    'position' => TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
    'align' => TabsX::ALIGN_LEFT,
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'gridview',
            'content' => $content_grid,//**want backend\view\companies\index.php page to open here... how to do it.. **
            'active' => true
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Basic Search',
            'content' => $content_basic_search,
            'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'font-weight:bold'],
            'options' => ['id' => 'myveryownID'],
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Dropdown',
            'items' => [
                 [
                     'label' => 'DropdownA',
                     'content' => 'DropdownA, Anim pariatur cliche...',
                 ],
                 [
                     'label' => 'DropdownB',
                     'content' => 'DropdownB, Anim pariatur cliche...',
                 ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

how to get that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using linkOptions?

```
'linkOptions'=>['data-url'=>\yii\helpers\Url::to(['backend/view/companies/index'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this widget before, but I think, it will help:

1. Add a BackendUrlManager in config (common/config/main.php):

   ```
   'components' => [
       'urlManagerBackend' => [
           'baseUrl' => 'http://backend.myproject.com', //Here you need to insert your backend app link
           'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager',
           'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
           'showScriptName' => false,
       ],
   ...
   ]
   ```
2. Use a link

   ```
   'linkOptions'=>['data-url'=>Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createAbsoluteUrl(['backend/view/companies/index'])])]
   ```

Comment: not working... trying to set unknownproperty urlManagerBackend

Comment: It should be in components part of config, I've fixed

Comment: what should be in $host??....Notice: Undefined variable: host in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-app\common\config\main.php on line 18